# How does Salesforce distinguish between a sandbox name and a second-level country code top-level domain?

Tags: sandbox, login, username

I've noticed that Salesforce allows for sandboxes to be created with 2 letter names, and there is no validation to prevent a conflict with country code top-level domain names.

If someone were to create a sandbox named `qa`, you might think that the system could have trouble distinguishing that suffix on a sandbox username from a second-level ccTLD. `name@company.com.qa` could be a production user with a Qatar domain username, or it could be a user of the `qa` sandbox with a plain `.com` username.

I ask specifically because I think that an issue related to this might explain why I can't log into the sandbox I created this morning. I created a sandbox named `qa`, and when logging into test.salesforce.com with username,

```
name@company.com.cn.qa (name@company.com.cn is my production username (except with my actual name and company name))
```

I got the following error message everytime I tried logging in throughout the day:

> INVALID_LOGIN: 用户名、密码、安全标记无效；或用户被锁定。
>   (Username, password, or security token is invalid; or user has been locked out)

I have had no trouble logging into my other sandboxes.

Comment: Salesforce will not create your sandbox user with the username productionusername.sandboxname in that case, but will append something extra to make it unique again. I remember having read this somewhere, but can't find the documentation right away.

Comment: @RobinDeBondt Interesting. When I click on the "login" button from the sandbox list in prod, it populates the username field on the login screen with `name@company.com.cn.qa`, but it is certainly believable that it isn't the true username value. It would be interesting to know what they added.

Comment: @RobinDeBondt. That info is located in Salesforce Help at https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_sandbox_implementation_tips.htm&language=en_US and only applies to Users and Contacts, not to sandbox names.

Comment: @crmprogdev That's what I meant as well. But I don't know how the 'Login' link in the Sandbox section in production works. Maybe it just tries to append the sandbox name to your username and log in? In that case, it will throw an error if your username in sandbox was modified twice because it wasn't unique the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce doesn't actually care about what your username is in terms of being a valid TLD or anything, it's just a string in an email-style format.

You can have the same username on a sandbox as on a production instance and it doesn't matter because you use a different URL to authenticate, i.e. test.salesforce.com or login.salesforce.com.

"bob@thisis.rubbish" is perfectly valid as a username.

Are you able to reset the password or does that say that you're using an invalid username? If the latter check the welcome email you received when the Sandbox was created to ensure you're definitely using the correct username, it may have used a format different to what you're expecting.

Comment: I never did get to the bottom of this one. I just refreshed that sandbox, and I was able to log in normally. I couldn't dig up the original welcome email, but interestingly this time the link had an error in it where the suffix they gave was `.com.cnqa` when the actual login credentials are `.com.cn.qa`.